# Как сделать Reverse для данного градиента при ховере?

Tags: css, градиент

Привет есть такой градиент

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, #fc5a83, #fd4362 33%, #ff8f5d);
```

Как сделать reverse при наведение если его позиция to bottom. Пробовал сделать ховер , получается если менять направление на to right. Но как сделать реверс если он to bottom

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvPbXB
Вот пример где видно как анимириуется если градиент идет to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fc5a83, #fd4362 15%, #ff8f5d 50%, #ff8f5d 55%, #fd4362 85%, #fc5a83);
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: auto 200%;
}
div:hover {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>Click Me</div>
```